# Convert from tcsh to bash

Tags: bash, tcsh

I'm trying to convert from a tcsh to bash. Things I have tried:

chsh

```
chsh -s /bin/bash

chsh: can only change local entries; use ypchsh instead
```

ypchsh

```
ypchsh /bin/bash

ypchsh: can't get local yp domain: Local domain name not set
```

I discovered I don't have sudo access after trying

```
sudo -s /bin/bash *username*
```

Then I tried creating a .cshrc file:

```
echo "I exist in .cshrc"

setenv SHELL /bin/bash
exec /bin/bash --login
```

When I do this however, I can't log in to my account. I enter my username and password and it looks like it's logging me in, but instead it kicks me back out to the login screen.

I know it has something to do with the last two lines, and not the file in general because I tested it again with just the `echo` command and I had no problems.

Comment: Have you tried editing the value in the `/etc/passwd` file?

Comment: I looked at that file, I don't know what value you are referring to, there wasn't a value pointing to a shell that I saw, and I don't know enough to add/modify anything in that without more instruction.

Comment: Sorry, I will be more clear: The file `/etc/passwd` has entries for every user. Find your user, and change the last value on the line to the shell you want. This means that all the other users on your system can use /etc/sh, but only your user has the new value set as the default. This will mean that any scripts referencing /bin/sh will not break.

Comment: Except I don't seem to have an entry here either. the entries are: root, bin, daemon, adm, lp, sync, sutdown, halt, mail, uucp, operator, games, gopher, ftp, nobody, dbus, rpc, usbmuxd, abrt, oprofile, vcsa, rtkit, hsqldb, avahi-autoipd, haldaemon, saslauth, postfix, rpcuser, nfsnobody, gdm, ntp, qemu, apache, mysql, pulse, sshd, tcdump, puppet, mailnull, smmsp, unbound

each of these is folowed by :x:###:###: comment: /somepath:/sbin/nologin, where the # is some number

Comment: Usually users are stored in `/etc/passwd`, but rarely they are stored elsewhere. `chsh` is supposed to deal with that for you, but if it doesn't, one can use `/etc/passwd` manually. I do not know much about default shells past this, though. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @Parallaxbeta: The response OP posted from `chsh` indicates this system is using [NIS-fka-YP=YellowPages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) which stores some, usually most, users in a central server NOT in the usual files `/etc/passwd /etc/shadow`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks! I didn't know about this system.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that the error was coming from the `exec /bin/bash --login` line. When I removed that the computer worked fine and I was in bash; however it wasn't running my bash startup file that had a number of different libraries I needed. Still not sure how to get those to load (without manually running `exec bin/bash`) on the original machine, but I actually run on a university server so I edited the .cshrc to the following:

```
echo "I exist in .chshrc"

setenv SHELL /bin/bash
if ($HOSTNAME = *server name*) then
    exec /bin/bash
end if
```

This seems to have solved my specific problems with this, though I doubt this is a general solution for anyone having this problem.